# SQL query for join on different values and aggregation with join

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relational-algebra

I need to write bunch of queries with a database with the following tables:

```
Match(homeId, awayId, homeScore, awayScore, date)

League(leagueId, leagueName)

Player(playerId, teamId, playerName, age, position, marketValue, position)

Team(teamId, teamName, leagueId, city)
```

However, I could not figure out how to write a sql query for the queries like following:

"Find the latest date when Lazio beat Milan in Milan’s home ground."
or
"Find the names of the leagues in which at least one team has at least three
Goalkeepers."

How can I join the Team table with Match table that will give me the matches with team names included. (i.e. homeId, awayId, homeName, awayName) and write these two queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is why I don't want whole answers, but I need some guidance as I am locked right now.

Comment: I did not try these on a actual sql server, I just need to write queries. I can write relational algebra queries but I cannot convert them to the sql.

Answer (score 0):

For your first requirement, you can use something like this.

```
    select date
    from match
    where homeid =(select teamid from team where  teamname = 'Milan')
    and awayId = (select teamid from team where  teamname = 'Lazio')
    and homeScore < awayScore
```

For second, use something like below.

```
    select l.leagueName
    from league l
    inner join Team t
    on l.leagueid=t.leagueid
    where t.teamid in (
    select distinct(teamid) as teamid from player p
    where p.position like 'Goalkeeper'
    group by teamid
    having count(*) >= 3)
```